# slimerjs Can not resolve required module encoding

Tags: node.js, slimerjs

I have seen [slimerjs Can not resolve required module, works with phantomjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496004/slimerjs-can-not-resolve-required-module-works-with-phantomjs), but that one explains absolutely nothing, so I'll dare ask the question again.

I have done this:

```
$ npm install -g encoding
encoding@0.1.12 /home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/encoding
└── iconv-lite@0.4.13
```

So, apparently, it should be there?

Now, I'm trying this test script, as stated in https://www.npmjs.com/package/encoding - let's call it `test_modload.js`:

```js
var encoding = require('encoding');
```

... and I try to run it with `node`:

```
$ node test_modload.js
module.js:338
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'encoding'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/test/test_modload.js:1:78)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
```

Apparently, here I have to use `NODE_PATH`:

```
NODE_PATH=/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules node test_modload.js
```

... and this command passes fine (i.e. returns nothing, and prints no errors).

But what if we try this with `casperjs`? The script becomes:

```js
var encoding = require('encoding');
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.run();
```

... and if I run with:

```
/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/casperjs/bin/casperjs test_modload.js
```

... again all is fine (i.e. returns nothing, and prints no errors).

But let's try this with `casperjs` with `slimerjs` engine:

```
$ SLIMERJSLAUNCHER=/usr/bin/firefox46 /home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/casperjs/bin/casperjs --engine=slimerjs test_modload.js 

Script Error: Module: Can not resolve "encoding" module required by main located at file:///home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/casperjs/bin/bootstrap.js
       Stack:
         -> file:///home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/casperjs/bin/bootstrap.js: 350
```

Eh... I guess `NODE_PATH` is missing?

```
$ NODE_PATH=/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules SLIMERJSLAUNCHER=/usr/bin/firefox46 /home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/casperjs/bin/casperjs --engine=slimerjs test_modload.js 

Script Error: Module: Can not resolve "encoding" module required by main located at file:///home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/casperjs/bin/bootstrap.js
       Stack:
         -> file:///home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/casperjs/bin/bootstrap.js: 350
```

Damn it, I ran out of options. What do I do now, how can I get `encoding` to work with `slimerjs`? Note that the `slimerjs` docs state in https://docs.slimerjs.org/current/api/require.html that one should use `require.paths`, however, for `node` standalone, it would complain with:

> Error: require.paths is removed. Use node_modules folders, or the NODE_PATH environment variable instead.

... while `slimerjs` doesn't output this error; but still, no change if I do `require.paths.push('/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules');` - it still 'can not resolve "encoding" module'.

Just to make sure I have the right path, here is a listing:

```
$ ls /home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules
casperjs  encoding  npm  utf8  zombie
$ ls /home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/encoding/
lib  LICENSE  node_modules  package.json  README.md  test
```

... so apparently the module is there.

So, how on earth can I get `slimerjs` to find and use the `encoding` module in a script?

Comment: You shouldn't globally install regular modules. Install it again using `npm i encoding` and try again.

Comment: Many thanks, @robertklep - tried it, but unfortunately that doesn't work; maybe it is because `casperjs` or `slimerjs` take over module loading? Really can't tell... I did try `strace`, and regular `node` which works does `open("/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/encoding/package.json", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 9`, however `casperjs`+`slimerjs` never even attempt to open anything in `/home/USERNAME/.nvm/` before crashing...

Comment: Try `strace -f ...`, I can imagine that CasperJS/SlimerJS use fork to create new processes, which by default aren't traced by `strace`

Comment: Thanks again, @robertklep - tried it; actually, I was wrong in my comment above: even without `strace -f`, the only path being loaded from is `/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/casperjs/bin`, but it never attempts to read anything else from `/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/`; unfortunately, `strace -f` doesn't reveal new info...

Comment: Perhaps SlimerJS doesn't work well with `nvm` and tries to find Node modules in their "regular" location (`/usr/local/lib/node_modules`)? Perhaps worth looking if it tries to access _anything_ with the name `encoding` (if you haven't already :-)

Comment: Indeed @robertklep - I found https://muffinresearch.co.uk/taming-slimerjs/ which explains `slimerjs` has a totally different way of loading modules; I managed to force-load `...encoding/lib/encoding.js`, but then it depends on `iconv-lite`, which has a `package.json` which `slimerjs` doesn't parse, and no singular .js file, so I guess some sort of a rewrite of `encoding.js` specially for `slimerjs` will be required.... damn it `:/`

Comment: I didn't take a look at what SlimerJS actually is, but it's based on Gecko instead of V8, so no wonder it's not working well with Node-specific stuff like `nvm` :-(

Comment: See also: [Can not resolve required module encoding · Issue #497 · laurentj/slimerjs · GitHub](https://github.com/laurentj/slimerjs/issues/497)