# Where/what is module.js?

Tags: node.js

I got this nasty error ([slimerjs Can not resolve required module encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748127/slimerjs-can-not-resolve-required-module-encoding)):

```
Error: Cannot find module 'encoding'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
...
```

... so I thought, maybe I could add a couple of `console.log` in this `module.js`, and thereby trace what files/paths are considered for loading.

However, I cannot seem to find this `module.js` anywhere:

```
$ find ~/.nvm/ -name 'module.js'  # nothing
$ find /path/to/slimerjs-0.10.1-pre -name module.js  # nothing
```

Then I go to https://github.com/nodejs/node/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=module.js - and I get a whole lot of hits, just not the file `module.js` `:/`

Where can I find this file? Also, is it somehow compiled inside `node`, as I cannot seem to find it standalone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here it is.](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/module.js) It's documented extensively [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html).

Yes, it's part of Node.js internals so you cannot modify it unless you want to build from source.

What you can do though is [attach a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1911015/476716) in order to trace what it's doing.

For future reference you were using the code search, [this is the file search](https://github.com/nodejs/node/find/master).